# Switching pages in NuGet crashes Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, postsharp

I'm a fan of NuGet package manager, and haven't had any problems before. Now if I

- Right click project solution.
- Manage NuGet Packages
- Click on the Installed Tab
- Try to click number "2" for second page

Then Visual Studio hangs with this image.

[image]

Clicking Cancel or exiting epically crashes Visual Studio.

I'm not sure where to start debugging this critical workflow block. Any ideas how I can get the package manager working again?

Note PostSharp3 was acting up before this started, no idea if that's related.  And VS takes an atrocious amount of time to start up for me.

**==== Update ====**

I uninstalled NuGet via Tools-->Extension Manager. When I restarted VS then PostSharp immediately prompted for NuGet to be installed. After installing, the problem still persisted.

Disabling post sharp did not help the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the codeplex site, you can post the issue to their issue tracker, the page here shows how to get the stack trace (its in the comments) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/06/08/how-to-get-call-stack-of-visual-studio.aspx

Then, go here and submitt new issue http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2876